# Get the value from the converter to the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

My goal is to get the mouse point location when the mouse moves over the given grid.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>     
  <helpers:MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter x:Key="mConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<Grid DataContext="{Binding CartesianChartVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}"   CommandParameter="ThePoint"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand
             Command="{Binding Main.MouseMoveCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
             EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource mConverter}"
             EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=ThePoint}"
             PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Where:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

The converter:

```
public class MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter : IEventArgsConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {
        var args = (MouseEventArgs)value;
        var element = (FrameworkElement)parameter;
        var point = args.GetPosition(element);
        return point;
    }
}
```

The view model:

```
    public ICommand MouseMoveCommand { get; private set; }
    private Point thePoint;

    public CartesianChartVM()
    {
        MouseMoveCommand = new RelayCommand(MouseMoveMethod);
    }
    void MouseMoveMethod()
    {
        Point p= ThePoint;
    }

    public Point ThePoint
    {
        get { return thePoint; }
        set
        {
            thePoint = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ThePoint");
        }
    }
```

> If I put breakpoint inside the converter class I can see the point coordinates, but how can I get this point value to the view model when mousemove event occures.
>
> I tried with `Point ThePoint` inside the view model but it's alwaws `(0,0)`, How do I pass the point value fom the converter class to the view model class?

Comment: shouldn't `MouseMoveMethod` accept arguments? Or am I misinterpreting `PassEventArgsToCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do next:

1. Set grid background to something that is not transparent. Transparent objects in wpf does not cathing mouse events. 
   `<Grid Background="#01FFFFFF">`
2. Create method with parameter for your command

   ```
   public ICommand DoSomething { get; private set; }

   public TestVM()
   {
       DoSomething = new RelayCommand<Point>(SomeAction);
   }

   private void SomeAction(Point point)
   {

   }
   ```
3. Save only one trigger and make it look like that one:

```html
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                <cmd:EventToCommand
             Command="{Binding DoSomething}"
             EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource mConverter}"
             PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used `CallMethodAction` from xaml. Its worth noting that I am using the new behaviors NuGet package which is described [in this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/)

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="mousepointerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mousepointerTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="3">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnMouseMove"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and here is my ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source);
    }
}
```

This does require you to know what type of event arguments get passed or else you will get a method signature match error.